# Order statistics $P(X_{i_1}<X_{i_2}<...<X_{i_n})=\frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables such that the transformation theorem conditions are satisfied. Prove that $P(X_{i_1}<X_{i_2}<...<X_{i_n})=\frac{1}{n!}$ for all permutations $(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ of $(1,2,...,n)$

I understand that there are $n!$ permutations of $(1,2,...,n)$ and each permutation is equally likely to occur so the possibility is $\frac{1}{n!}$.But why do we need transformation theorem?

Comment: We need some conditions, such as $\Pr(X_i=X_j)=0$ if $i\ne j$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Let's say that $X_i$'s are continuous

Comment: Then you are right, that is enough to get $\frac{1}{n!}$, by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_{1}, \ldots X_{n}$ are continuous their cdf $F$ is also continuous. Since $F$ is monotonic increasing,

\begin{align*}
  P(X_{i_1} < X_{i_2} < \ldots  < X_{i_n}) = P(F^{-1}(X_{i_1}) < F^{-1}(X_{i_2}) < \ldots  < F^{-1}(X_{i_n}))
\end{align*}

Observe that, for every $j$, $F^{-1}(X_{i_j}) \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$.

Hence, your problem boils down to proving that, if $U_{1}, \ldots U_{n}$ are i.i.d. random variables with $U_{i} \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, then $P(U_{i_1} < U_{i_2} < \ldots  < U_{i_n}) = (n!)^{-1}$.

Observe that $\{u \in R^{n}: u_{i_1} < u_{i_2} < \ldots < u_{i_n}\}$ all have the same volume. Hence, since there are n! disjoint sets corresponding to each permutation, the result follows.